# Error Plantilla con Angularjs y Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

He descargado una plantilla gratis y estoy tratando de ajustarla con angularjs, pero el problema que tengo es que las animaciones, carruseles de imágenes o la navegación entre divs no funciona.

Quisiera saber que debo hacer para poder solucionar este problema

a continuación comparto lo que tengo:

index .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> 
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <!--Angularjs-->
        <script src="angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angularjs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angularjs/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/features.mod.js"></script>
        <script src="app/logueo/login.ctrl.js"></script>
        <!--Web-->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Meghna One page parallax responsive HTML Template ">

        <meta name="author" content="Muhammad Morshed">

        <title>Qorner | Reserva de canchas sintéticas</title>

        <!-- Mobile Specific Meta
        ================================================== -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.png" />

        <!-- CSS
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Fontawesome Icon font -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- bootstrap.min css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Animate.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <!-- Owl Carousel -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
        <!-- Grid Component css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css">
        <!-- Slit Slider css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slit-slider.css">
        <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <!-- Media Queries -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media-queries.css">

        <!--
        Google Font
        =========================== -->                    

        <!-- Oswald / Title Font -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- Ubuntu / Body Font -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- Modernizer Script for old Browsers -->     
        <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body id="body" ng-app="starter">
        <!--
        Start Preloader
        ==================================== -->
        <div id="loading-mask">
            <div class="loading-img">
                <img alt="Meghna Preloader" src="img/preloader.gif"  />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--
        End Preloader
        ==================================== -->
        <main>      
            <div ui-view></div> 
        </main>
        <footer id="footer" class="bg-one">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="500ms">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <!-- Footer Social Links -->
                        <div class="social-icon">
                            <ul>
                                <li><img src="img/quercusIcon.png" alt="Meghna" width="200" height="150" /></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="copyright text-center">             
                            <p>Desarrollado por QuercusDev. Copyright &copy; 2017. Totdos los derechos reservados.</p>
                            <br>
                            <div class="portfolio-filter clearfix">
                                <ul class="text-center">
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> | @quercusdev</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> | @quercusdev</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> | @quercusdev</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>                  
                    </div> <!-- end col lg 12 -->
                </div> <!-- end row -->
            </div> <!-- end container -->
        </footer> <!-- end footer -->

        <!-- Back to Top
        ============================== -->
        <a href="javascript:;" id="scrollUp">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-2x"></i>
        </a>

        <!-- end Footer Area
        ========================================== -->

        <!-- 
        Essential Scripts
        =====================================-->

        <!-- Main jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap 3.1 -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Slitslider -->
        <script src="js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Parallax -->
        <script src="js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>
        <!-- Owl Carousel -->
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Portfolio Filtering -->
        <script src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom Scrollbar -->
        <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Jappear js -->
        <script src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
        <!-- Pie Chart -->
        <script src="js/easyPieChart.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery Easing -->
        <script src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
        <!-- Highlight menu item -->
        <script src="js/jquery.nav.js"></script>
        <!-- Sticky Nav -->
        <script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
        <!-- Number Counter Script -->
        <script src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
        <!-- wow.min Script -->
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <!-- For video responsive -->
        <script src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
        <!-- Grid js -->
        <script src="js/grid.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom js -->
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Login html (vista con problema):

```
<!-- Welcome Slider ==================================== -->
<section id="home">     

    <div id="slitSlider" class="sl-slider-wrapper">
        <div class="sl-slider">

            <!-- single slide item -->
            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-25" data-slice2-rotation="-25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="2">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-1"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <div>
                        <h2 data-wow-duration="500ms"  data-wow-delay="500ms" class="heading animated fadeInRight">Bienvenido
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /single slide item -->

            <!-- single slide item -->
            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="10" data-slice2-rotation="-15" data-slice1-scale="1.5" data-slice2-scale="1.5">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-2"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="heading animated fadeInDown">Highly Responsive</h2>
                        <h3 class="animated fadeInUp">With all Mejor Browser support including IE 9</h3>
                        <a class="btn btn-green animated fadeInUp" href="#">Get Started</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /single slide item -->

            <!-- single slide item -->
            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="3" data-slice2-rotation="3" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-3"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="heading animated fadeInRight">One Page Parallax HTML Template</h2>
                        <h3 class="animated fadeInLeft">Clean and Professional Design</h3>
                        <a class="btn btn-green animated fadeInUp" href="#">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /single slide item -->

        </div><!-- /sl-slider -->

        <nav id="nav-arrows" class="nav-arrows">
            <span class="nav-arrow-prev">Previous</span>
            <span class="nav-arrow-next">Next</span>
        </nav>

        <nav id="nav-dots" class="nav-dots">
            <span class="nav-dot-current"></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </nav>

    </div><!-- /slider-wrapper -->
</section>
<!--/#home section-->

<!-- 
Fixed Navigation
==================================== -->
<header id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- responsive nav button -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- /responsive nav button -->

            <!-- logo -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#body">
                <h1 id="logo">
                    <span class="color">Qorner</span>
                </h1>
            </a>
            <!-- /logo -->
        </div>

        <!-- main nav -->
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="Navigation">
            <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="current"><a href="#body">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">¿Cómo funciona?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#showcase">Ej</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Ej2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pricing">Ej3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact-us">Ej4</a></li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-transparent" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">   
                        Inicio de sesión
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /main nav -->

    </div>
</header>
<section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="500ms">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <!-- section title -->
                <div class="title text-center">
                    <h2><span class="color">Canchas sintéticas</span></h2>
                    <div class="border"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- /section title -->

                <!-- portfolio item filtering -->
                <div class="portfolio-filter clearfix">
                    <ul class="text-center">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter" data-filter="all">Todas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter" data-filter=".app">Norte</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter" data-filter=".web">Centro</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter" data-filter=".photoshop">Sur</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter" data-filter=".illustrator">¿Quieres formar parte de esta comunidad?</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /portfolio item filtering -->

            </div> <!-- /end col-lg-12 -->
        </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div>  <!-- end container -->

    <!-- portfolio items -->
    <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="500ms">
        <ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">

            <!-- single portfolio item -->  
            <li class="mix app">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Azuki bean</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix web">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Veggies sunt bona vobis</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix photoshop">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Dandelion horseradish</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix illustrator">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Qplay" data-description="Si posees una cancha sintética y quieres unirte a nuestra comunidad, contacta con nosotros.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Quiero unirme</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix app">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Azuki bean</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix app">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Veggies sunt bona vobis</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>  
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix web">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Dandelion horseradish</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>  
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix photoshop">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Azuki bean</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix photoshop">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Veggies sunt bona vobis</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix web">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Dandelion horseradish</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

            <!-- single portfolio item -->
            <li class="mix app">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                    <div class="hover-mask">
                        <h3>Azuki bean</h3>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /single portfolio item -->

        </ul> <!-- end og grid -->
    </div>  <!-- portfolio items wrapper -->

</section>   <!-- End section -->
```

finalmente cuando agrego estas secciones en mi index no hay problema jquery trabaja correctamente pero si lo dejo en la parte que deseo Login html no funcion
De antemano les agradezco

Comment: ¿Qué error tienes?

Comment: la verdad que ninguno,